Why does diffeomorphism invariance not imply all physical theories are Poincare invariant?
It is said that diffeomorphisms are global symmetries of all theories with fixed background geometry, and local symmetry of gravitational theories i.e. theories with dynamical metric. In the case where diffeomorphisms are global symmetries, isn't it obvious that all background dependent theories are Poincare invariant, since Poincare transformations are obviously a subset of Diffeomorphisms? But we know that not all theories are not Poincare invariant. E.g. Newtonian gravitation.
A different formulation of the same question is as follows:
Poincare transformations are isometries of the the base space, while doing relativistic field theory on flat spacetime. So diffeomorphisms can't be a gauge symmetry because we fixed the background. But how is it even a global symmetry here? The isometries induce some action on the fields, and while writing down the theory (i.e. the action), we write down invariants under the isometries, and not a general coordinate transformation, right? So, what exactly does people even mean, when they say diffeomorphisms are global symmetries of all theories or more handwavingly "Physics does not depend on coordinates", when at the end they write theories invariant under the isometries of the base space (and ofcourse kill some terms and include some other kind of transformations acting on the fields directly to get interesting physics...but that's beside the point).
